# Storing Data from WinCC Flex to Excel file using VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript, wincc

Am trying to log data of some tags of WinCC Flex into Excel file using VB Script.
I've searched on Siemens forums and have got an script according to my needs.
But there is an error while executing the script in WinCC Flex.

The script is as:

```
Dim wsh, XLSrunning, TargetBookrunning, objExcelApp, objWorkbook, TheTargetBook,    TheTargetBookName
Dim TheCount
Dim objFSO
Const OverwriteExisting = 1


Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    TheTargetBookName = "report.xls"
    TheTargetBook = "D:\Out\" & TheTargetBookName

'---------------[Modification#1_Begin]-------------------------------------------
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not objFSO.FileExists(TheTargetBook) Then
       objFSO.CopyFile "D:\Out\Template.xls", TheTargetBook, OverwriteExisting
       'HMIRuntime.Trace "The file," & TheTargetBook & ", does not exist." & vbCrLf & "I've just created one for you!"
End If
Set objFSO = Nothing    

'---------------[Modification#1_End]--------------------------------------------

TheCount = GetObject("winmgmts:root\CIMV2").ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name='EXCEL.EXE'").Count   
'While TheCount is bigger than 0, it means the Excel Application is running..., but doesn't mean the workbook is open for sure!

If TheCount > 0 Then
   Set objExcelApp = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")
                 ' Using GetObject(,"Excel.Application") to point to the running Excel Application.

       TargetBookrunning = 0  
       For Each XLSrunning In objExcelApp.Workbooks
           If XLSrunning.name = TheTargetBookName Then
              TargetBookrunning = 1
           End If
       Next
       If TargetBookrunning = 1 Then
          Set objWorkbook = GetObject(TheTargetBook)
       Else
          Set objWorkbook = objExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(TheTargetBook)
       End If
Else

  Set objExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  Set objWorkbook = objExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(TheTargetBook)

End If

      objExcelApp.Visible = True
      objExcelApp.ScreenUpdating = True
      objExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = True

      Dim TheTargetRow       ' <------[Modification#2]-------
      With objWorkbook.ActiveSheet

        TheTargetRow = .Cells(65535, 2).End(-4162).Row
                .cells(TheTargetRow + 1, 2) = SmartTags("Tag_1")
                .cells(TheTargetRow + 1, 3) = SmartTags("Tag_2")
                .cells(TheTargetRow + 1, 4) = SmartTags("Tag_3")         

      End With 
      objWorkbook.Save
     'objWorkbook.Close

  Set objWorkbook = Nothing
     'objExcelApp.Quit
  Set objExcelApp = Nothing
  'MsgBox "Done"

Set wsh = Nothing
```

When, I try to execute this script, the compiler shows the error in following line:

```
 TheTargetRow = .Cells(65535, 2).End(-4162).Row
```

Am unable to determine the error. Please do the needful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you show is mostly correct, but actually the problem in that line has something to do with the implementation of the VBScript interface inside the WINCC environment.

If you created a new variable called "theSheet" to hold the reference to the Excel 
worksheet, you would still avoid that syntax checking problem in WinCC.

This way would allow you to access from it to its Cells object, but seems to me that there is no an obvious way to directly return the value of the ".End(xlUp).Row" property, though.

However, the only purpose that the "Row" value looks to have is getting the row number where to print the tag values out. Check the next code and see how you feel with the result.

```
Dim wsh, XLSrunning, TargetBookrunning, objExcelApp, objWorkbook, TheTargetBook, TheTargetBookName
Dim TheCount, theSheet, theCell, theLastCell,  theLastRow
Dim objFSO
Const OverwriteExisting = 1


Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    'TheTargetBookName = "report.xls"
    'TheTargetBook = "D:\Out\" & TheTargetBookName

    TheTargetBookName = "report.xls"
    TheTargetBook = "f:\work\plc\" & TheTargetBookName
    TheTargetBookName = "c:\" & TheTargetBookName

'---------------[Modification#1_Begin]-------------------------------------------
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not objFSO.FileExists(TheTargetBook) Then
       objFSO.CopyFile TheTargetBookName, TheTargetBook, OverwriteExisting
       'HMIRuntime.Trace "The file," & TheTargetBook & ", does not exist." & vbCrLf & "I've just created one for you!"
End If
Set objFSO = Nothing    

'---------------[Modification#1_End]--------------------------------------------

TheCount = GetObject("winmgmts:root\CIMV2").ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name='EXCEL.EXE'").Count   
'While TheCount is bigger than 0, it means the Excel Application is running..., but doesn't mean the workbook is open for sure!

If TheCount > 0 Then
   Set objExcelApp = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")
                 ' Using GetObject(,"Excel.Application") to point to the running Excel Application.

       TargetBookrunning = 0  
       For Each XLSrunning In objExcelApp.Workbooks
           If XLSrunning.name = TheTargetBookName Then
              TargetBookrunning = 1
           End If
       Next
       If TargetBookrunning = 1 Then
          Set objWorkbook = GetObject(TheTargetBook)
       Else
          Set objWorkbook = objExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(TheTargetBook)
       End If
Else

  Set objExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  Set objWorkbook = objExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(TheTargetBook)

End If

      objExcelApp.Visible = True
      objExcelApp.ScreenUpdating = True
      objExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = True

      Dim TheTargetRow       ' <------[Modification#2]-------
      Set theSheet = objWorkbook.ActiveSheet
      With theSheet
        Set theCell = theSheet.Cells(65535,2)
        Set theLastCell  = theCell.end(-4162)
        theLastRow = theLastCell.row
        .cells(theLastRow + 1, 1) = formatdatetime( now,vbShortDate) & ", " & formatdatetime( now,vbLongTime)
        .cells(theLastRow + 1, 2) = SmartTags("Tag_1")
        .cells(theLastRow + 1, 3) = SmartTags("Tag_2")
        .cells(theLastRow + 1, 4) = SmartTags("Tag_3")         
      End With 
      objWorkbook.Save
     'objWorkbook.Close

  Set objWorkbook = Nothing
     'objExcelApp.Quit  
  Set objExcelApp = Nothing
  'MsgBox "Done"

Set wsh = Nothing
```